# In gtkmm, How to imply function which can create a new window when detach a notebook tab?

Tags: c++, gtkmm

It seems that there's a signal named 'create-window' available in gtk. But I can't find relative signals in gtkmm.

Comment: When I developed with gtkmm 2.4, it happened to me from time to time that something like e.g. a signal of GTK+ was not bound in gtkmm. I solved this by retrieving the GTK+ object from its gtkmm wrapper object and using the GTK+ API directly. You have to be a bit carefully but, in my cases, it always solved the lack of gtkmm.

Comment: Thank you for your advice. I tried "g_signal_connect" and "create-window" signal in GTK+ API and it seemed work well with gtkmm.

Comment: I still think it would be more natural and easy, if there could be an approach in Gtkmm.

Comment: I switched from gtkmm to Qt a while ago as I became concerned about the lack of Windows support with gtkmm 3. (Windows is the first choice of our customers - not mine. This was a hard decision as I liked gtkmm very much in general. We even considered to become active in the Windows port but dropped this option due to concerns of our management.) ;-) However, in gtkmm 2.4, I was used to the fact that the "more interesting" features like e.g. drag-n-drop were not well covered by the gtkmm binding. (but I've no idea about gtkmm 3.)